# Why arguments are zeroed at WebAssembly imported function call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webassembly

I manually generated a WASM module that decompiles by `wasm2wat` into the following code.

```
(module
  (type (;0;) (func))
  (type (;1;) (func (param i32 i32)))
  (import "std" "print" (func (;0;) (type 1)))
  (func (;1;) (type 0)
    i32.const 0
    i32.const 13
    call 0)
  (memory (;0;) 13)
  (export "main" (func 0))
  (export "data" (memory 0))
  (data (;0;) (i32.const 0) "Hello, world!"))
```

At Node site I instantiate the module, supplying the following imports.

```
const imports = {
  std: {
    print: (utf8Offset, utf8Length) => {
      console.log([utf8Offset, utf8Length]);
      ...
    },
  },
};
```

When `main` function runs, `console.log` reports two zeros instead of `0` and `13`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved. I didn't take into account that functions are numbered starting from imports, not from in-module definitions.

`main` export should look like this:

```
(export "main" (func 1))
```